# Dynamically Changing Joint Velocities Moveit!

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just wondering if the function 'scaleMaxVel' is functional in the current version of Moveit!
I have a robotic arm that I need to scale its velocity for various movements.

Any help would be much appreciated and if there is an alternative method for achieving this in C++ if this function is not functional.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221735/dynamically-changing-joint-velocities-moveit!/) by [GeorgeWalsh92](https://answers.ros.org/users/25210/georgewalsh92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Time Parameterization Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/time_parameterization_tutorial.html?highlight=velocity) tutorial talks about velocity scaling for joints and eefs.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0